# Replace one of annotation parameters with IntelliJ IDEA's Structural replace

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations, structural-search

I have many classes with the Spring `@ContextConfiguration` annotation. The annotation has the `classes` parameter, which can be an array.

Now most of my classes look like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)         
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
        ThisShellBeTwoClassesInContextHierarchyConfig.class,
        SomeTest.SomeTestConfig.class,
        WhateverConfig.class
})
@Transactional
public class SomeTest { ...
```

Desired output of some magical batch operation would be following:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)         
@ContextHierarchy(classes = {
        @ContextConfiguration(classes = { ConfigA.class }),
        @ContextConfiguration(classes = { ConfigB.class }),
        @ContextConfiguration(classes = {
            SomeTest.SomeTestConfig.class,
            WhateverConfig.class
        })
})
@Transactional
public class SomeTest { ...
```

So far, I was not even able to have the IntelliJ IDEA Structural replace tool find annotations with the `classes` parameter, let alone replacing it.
Even simplified structure like this

```
@$Annotation$($param$ = { $ctx$ })
```

doesn't find anything. The occurrences of `ctx` are set to unlimited.

How should I properly work with the annotation parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that because of [a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-176381) it is not possible to match arrays (ElementValueArrayInitializer) in annotation name-value pairs. You can match the annotation you want using a query like:

```
@$Annotation$($param$ = $value$)
```

But this is probably not very helpful.