# How to structurally replace value of one parameter of an annotation in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations, structural-search

I have classes annotated with
`@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_gen",/*other_parameters*/)`
I need to replace `"seq_gen"` with `"$Class$_seq_gen"` in each class.

I've tried following.

**Search**

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_gen")
class $Class$ {}
```

**Replacement**

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "$Class$_seq_gen")
class $Class$ {}
```

When I run the replacement the `/*other_parameters*/` part gets removed.

I also tried

**Search**

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "$VALUE$")
class $Class$ {}
```

**Replacement**

```
"$Class$_$VALUE$"
```

with `$VALUE$` as target, it does not remove anything now but replaces with `_seq_gen` as if `$Class$` was not defined.

How can I accomplish this? Documentation of SSR is quite confusing and not detailed.

---

I've found this question through search on SO, but it doesn't have and actual answer and is really about issue with arrays. [Replace one of annotation parameters with IntelliJ IDEA's Structural replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45148556/replace-one-of-annotation-parameters-with-intellij-ideas-structural-replace)

Comment: Can you somehow use `name= " seq_gen", $param$ = $value$` with multiple occurrences of the latter?

Comment: If I do it like that and specify `1, ∞` for `$param$` and `$value$` the result comes out with the latter part as `$param$ $param$ = $value$, $value` O_o E.g. `@SequenceGenerator(name = "BankAccountTurnover_seq_gen", sequenceName allocationSize = "bank_account_turnovers_seq",1)`

Comment: The patterns in the question work without problems in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3 (which is in early access program at thee moment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This used to be difficult to accomplish because of a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65982) in Structural Search relating to annotation parameters. This bug has been fixed. Currently you can use the first suggestion in the question:

Search template:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_gen")
class $Class$ {}
```

Replacement template:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "$Class$_seq_gen")
class $Class$ {}
```

##### Old workaround

Previously a workaround was needed, which used a replacement variable and Groovy script. Like the following search template:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = $value$)
class $Class$ {}
```

##### $value$ constraints

text/regexp: `"seq_gen"` (including quotes)
This variable is target of the search: enabled

Replacement template:

```
$replacement$
```

##### $replacement$ script constraints

script text:

```
import com.intellij.psi.util.PsiTreeUtil
import com.intellij.psi.PsiClass

def x = PsiTreeUtil.getParentOfType(value, PsiClass.class);
"\"" + x.name + "_seq_gen\""
```

Comment: Bug shows as fixed

Comment: I have updated my answer with the best way to accomplish the task, now that the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I've found an ugly work around, just do this for all possible N:

Search:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "$VALUE$", $param1$ = $value1$,/*...*/ $paramN$ = $valueN$)
class $Class$ {}
```

Replacement:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "$Class$_$VALUE$", $param1$ = $value1$,/*...*/ $paramN$ = $valueN$)
class $Class$ {}
```

I really don't want this to be the real answer, so I won't be accepting it for the duration of the next week, in hopes that someone provides a better answer :)

Comment: I'm struggling with this to make my life easier with replacing Spring's `@RequestMapping` annotation to a specialized ones. i.e. `@GetMapping`. Unfortunately, this solution works only if you have fixed number of annotation parameters. In my case number of parameters very, hence it leaves me with: `@GetMapping(path = "/xxx", consumes = "xxx", produces = "xxx",  = ,  = ,  = ,  = )`